# Understanding how long long int get stored?

Tags: c++

I am running following program: (URL: http://ideone.com/aoJoI5)

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cmath>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
     long long int N=pow(2, 36);
     cout << N <<endl;
     int count = 0;
     cout << "Positions where bits are set : " << endl;
     for(int j=0; j<sizeof(long long int)*8; ++j){
     if(N&(1<<j)){
        ++count;
        cout << j << endl;
     }
   }
  return 0;
}
```

This program gives me output as:

```
 68719476736
 Positions where bits are set : 
 31
 63
```

Now as I am using N=2^36, which means 36th bit should be 1 and nothing else, but why program gives me position 31 and 63? is anything wrong with my program?

I have one observation that if we use N=2^{exp} where exp >= 32 it always give positions for set bit to be 31 and 63. Can anybody please explain why this happens?

Comment: `1<<j` may cause shifting too much. `1ull<<j` should be used instead.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks that worked.

Comment: @MikeCAT: Please do not use the comments section for answers. If you do not want the rep, you can give back to the community by bountying it away.

Comment: It's important to know that not all shifts have defined behaviour. Shift too much for a type and you end up in undefined behaviour land.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `int` is 32-bit long, `1<<j` will do shifting too much and invoke *undefined behavior*.

Here is my guess of the cause:

1. When `j` becomes 31, the `1` bit comes to the sign bit.
2. Seeing the sign bit being 1, to calculate bitwise AND with `N`, the value is sign-extended, so bits from 31st to 63th (0-origin) become 1.
3. The 36th bit (0-origin) in `N` is 1, so the result of bitwise AND will be nonzero.
4. The condition is evaluated as true and the number is printed.
5. When `j` is 63, if you use IA-32 CPU, the width to be shifted is masked to 5 bits, so it will be interpreted as 31 and the same thing will happen.

To avoid this *undefined behavior*, use `unsigned long long` value to shift like `1ull<<j`.
Note that using `long long` is not good because shifting the `1` bit to sign bit invokes *undefined behavior*.